# d3 axis orientation: center

Tags: d3.js

in D3, how can I put an axis in the middle, or center, of a graph? The [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes) says "only top/bottom/left/right".

I know the dimensions of my graph, let's say it is 400px by 400px. In Protovis I used

`vis.add(pv.Rule).bottom(200)`

placing an axis 200px up from the bottom. How can I do this in D3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can transform the axes whichever way you want. The orientation only refers to which side the ticks and numbers are placed on.

See e.g. http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/axes/

```
svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
 .call(xAxis);
```

where you just need to change the parameter to the transform to get whatever you want.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Actually I came from the tutorial that you have linked to and tried it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/8DDVN/11/ . This fiddle contains your code. Having just started with D3, and having a lot to read and understand ahead of me in order to move from Protovis to D3, I am stuck for the moment. Would you, or anyone be so kind and move that x-axis just a little? That would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: The most general thing I can think of is to try to take the attitude "It's simpler and easier than you think". Because remember that d3 is all the time about very simply generating stuff into the browser's DOM.

Comment: thanks a lot, that worked, answer happily accepted. (If it was indeed "simpler than I thought" however, then there would have been a     axis.orient(["center"])  lol, but that is probably silly when you've understood transform, translate etc.